# How to show ionic spinner in the centre position of the screen?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a spinner in my ionic project. I want to put the spinner in the centre position of the screen. But it always shows up in the left top corner as:

[image]

Html file is:

```
<div *ngIf="spinner == 'true'">
   <ion-spinner name="bubbles"></ion-spinner>
</div>
```

My scss file is:

```
page-login {
    ion-spinner {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    stroke: #444;
    fill: #222;
  }
}
```

Can you help?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I find the solution finally. Add a class spin and set text align center.

```
<div class="spin" *ngIf="spinner == 'true'">
    <ion-spinner name="bubbles"></ion-spinner>
</div>

.spin{
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 }
 ion-spinner {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    stroke: #444;
    fill: #222;
 }
```

Comment: i think we need plus one every month for plus those answers that help us every month... like this answer... thanks this helped  me for the second time

Comment: why you used `position:fixed` ? May I know please

Answer (score 3):

You can even center the loader using the `flexbox` property in css. Try this

```
<div class="spin" *ngIf="spinner == 'true'">
   <ion-spinner name="bubbles"></ion-spinner>
</div>

.spin{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why add a separate div tag above the ion-spinner?

Here's the best way to do it:

```
<ion-spinner name="bubbles" class="page-loader" *ngIf="showPageLoader"></ion-spinner>

.page-loader{
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a class spin and set text align center.

```
 <div class="spin" *ngIf="spinner == 'true'">
        <ion-spinner name="bubbles"></ion-spinner>
 </div>

.spin{
    text-align: center;
  }
  ion-spinner {
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    stroke: #444;
    fill: #222;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. It works but not perfect. Now it is in the centre of top line. Can you make it in the centre of screen?

Answer (score 1):

```
<pre>
<ion-spinner></ion-spinner>

ion-spinner {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    height: 5em;
    width: em;
    overflow: show;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
</pre>
```

Thats what I did.
Forgot the question I got help from.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me like this:

```
<div class="ion-text-center" *ngIf="spinner == 'true'">
   <ion-spinner name="bubbles"></ion-spinner>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the spinner inside an  tag and set the align property of  to center :

```css
 div.loading-spinner{
    text-align: center;
  }
```